# store the query output into a variable in Redshift Postgresql

Tags: shell, amazon-redshift

How to store the query output into a variable in Redshift Postgresql?

for example:

I want to store the output of below query in to a variable.

`select count(1) from abcd;`

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have "variables". Does Redshift?

Comment: I will be executing the SQL statement using shell script and i need to store the value in a variable and do some calculations.

Comment: So, `var=$(psql -qAt -c "query")` ... ? . This sort of thing doesn't scale well, though, and I recommend using a "real" scripting language like Python + psycopg2, Perl + DBD::Pg, Ruby + the Pg gem, etc.

Comment: If you need it for a query you can use WITH (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store values in a temporary table. You can compute one or more values, store them in a temporary table, and reference them later in the session.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
variables AS (

    SELECT     'X' AS variable_name,
               COUNT(*) AS variable_value
    FROM       table_name

);

SELECT    * 
FROM      variables;
```